# Swift: How can i get height of an object with the camera?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uikit

Hi i would like measure an object in 'cm' (or similar) of an object obtained with the camera

Any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried anything at all? This isn't a place where we do all your homework.

Comment: I´m asking for an idea not for somebody whoe makes my homework..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a precise measurement. 
You would need to input roughly how far away the object is from the camera in inches.

You need to measure how many pixels tall the item is that you want to measure.
Using the pixels measured, combined with the DPI of the camera and the distance the camera is from that object and some estimated angles then you can work out an approximate height of the object in inches using trigonometry.